# Invalid Argument Exception when generating Entities from existing database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm converting a Symfony 2 project from Propel to Doctrine and wish to convert the existing database into Doctrine Entities.

To do this I'm following the [tutorial on the Symfony website](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), however when I run the following command:

`php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force`

I immediately receive the following error:

```
[InvalidArumentException]
Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist.
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong and how I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found out what was causing the error. It appears that the doctrine configuration settings within config.yml require a parameter called `auto_mapping: true`.

For example:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

More information can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/doctrine.html