# Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a trouble while creating new entity in my Custom CMS Bundle . At the end of generating through this error :

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>    Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist.

However , I have tried to solve  [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409342/invalid-argument-exception-when-generating-entities-from-existing-database) . 
 But in this case I got another error :

> ClassNotFoundException in DoctrineExtension.php line 432:
>   Attempted to load class "Version" from namespace "Doctrine\ORM".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Jackalope\Version\Version", "Doctrine\DBAL\Version", "Symfony\Component\Intl\Util\Version", "Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Version", "Doctrine\Common\Cache\Version" or "Doctrine\Common\Version"?

What shold I do ? how to fix that ?

Comment: There can be several things, wrong namespace,  Add the actual code from line 432. Have you used command:$composer install --dev recently?

Comment: ` if (version_compare(Version::VERSION, "2.3.0-DEV") >= 0) {
            $methods = array_merge($methods, array(
                'setNamingStrategy' => new Reference($entityManager['naming_strategy']),
                'setQuoteStrategy' => new Reference($entityManager['quote_strategy']),
            ));
        }` this is code from line 432 . unrecognized VERSION . However this code uses `    use Doctrine\ORM\Version;`

Comment: Its most likely namespace issue. I am guessing you are calling some class that system is looking for in the same folder as current class file. It could also be a very basic thing like you are not declaring namespace or 'use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;'

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and it was a configuration problem.

I added the following lines in */app/config/config.yml* file and it solved the issue :

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        auto_mapping: true
```

Used with Symfony 3.4 version.